# How to loop over multiple lists

Tags: r

I am working with precipitation data for four river basins. The four rivers are Main, Danube, Isar and Inn. The precipitation data set is organised in an array (dimensions are `150 150 80`). The third dimension respresents the single time steps. For every river basin I have a matrix called "mask_rivername", so "mask_Main", "mask_Danube" etc. Each matrix is of dimensions `150 150`. The goal is to multiply the single matrices with every single time step of the precipitation data.
To achieve this, I created a list for every river called "Main.list", "Danube.list", "Isar.list" and "Inn.list".
Now I would like to fill the single lists, for example by using a loop. If I do that one by one it works well:

```
for (i in 1:ntime) {
  Main.list[[paste0("Main.rr",i)]] <- PRECIPITATION[,,i]*mask_Main
  Danube.list[[paste0("Danube.rr",i)]] <- PRECIPITATION[,,i]*mask_Danube
  Isar.list[[paste0("Isar.rr",i)]] <- PRECIPITATION[,,i]*mask_Isar
  Inn.list[[paste0("Inn.rr",i)]] <- PRECIPITATION[,,i]*mask_Inn
}
```

I am sure there must be a more elegant way, but I could not find it. My problem is that `get(paste0())` does not work at the beginning of a loop.

Anybody here with a hint?

Comment: Can you post a smaller subset of your matrix, say, `dput(PRECIPITATION[1:10, 1:10, 1:4])` and of at least one `mask_`, ideally all 4?

Comment: Well the exact values are not so important. You can basically use any array for ```PRECIPITATION``` values and any matrix for the ```mask_ values``` as long as the dimensions are the same.
For example ```mask_Main <- matrix(-1:1, nrow = 150, ncol = 150)``` and ```PRECIPITATION <- array(-500:500, dim = c(150, 150, 80))```. That should be sufficent to reproduce everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be answered the R way with a double `lapply` loop. As long as both arguments, the precipitation array and the masks are in list objects. That's what the preliminary code does, to create two lists.

```
mask_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^mask_", envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
nmat <- dim(PRECIPITATION)[3]
precip_list <- lapply(seq.int(nmat), function(i) PRECIPITATION[,, i])

new_precip <- lapply(mask_list, function(x, y){
  lapply(y, function(.y) .y * x)
}, y = precip_list)

rivers <- sub("^mask_", "", names(mask_list))
new_precip <- lapply(seq_along(new_precip), function(i){
  names(new_precip[[i]]) <- paste(rivers[i], seq.int(nmat), sep = ".")
  new_precip[[i]]
})
names(new_precip) <- rivers
```

To have this result as lists in the `.GlobalEnv`, you can use `list2env`.

**Test data**

```
PRECIPITATION <- array(-199:200, dim = c(10, 10, 4))
mask_Main <- 
  mask_Danube <-
  mask_Isar <-
  mask_Inn <- matrix(-1:1, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it does not seem to do what I was looking for. As described in the question, the output should be four lists, each one containing 80 single elements (resulting from ```mask_river``` multiplied with the number of time steps (80) of the PRECIPITATION data). When I apply your code, the result is just one list containing 80 elements. But I need the 4 lists (```"Main.list", "Danube.list", "Isar.list" and "Inn.list"```) each one containing 80 respectively ```ntime``` elements.

Comment: @climdrag OK, I think I've got it now, see the edit.

Comment: @climdrag Sorry, wrong again. This time I really, really think it's right.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It seems to work indeed now, there are four lists included in ```new_precip```. Now only the last step, getting the results to the ```.GlobalEnv``` makes troubles. When I do ```list2env(new_precip, .GlobalEnv)``` I receive the error message ```Error in list2env(list, envir = .GlobalEnv) : names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x```. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @climdrag Yes, there's a small bug, the code line `names(new_precip) <- rivers` should be *after* the last `lapply` loop. Will correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it worked entirely! I must admit that I was hoping that there is an easier and/or shorter solution to achieve this.